# How can I disassociate my main Stack Exchange account from my teams account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, accounts

From time to time, I log out of Stack Overflow so that I can focus on my day-to-day activities.  But I'm presented with a challenge:  I recently started a trial of teams at my institution, so I'd like to remain signed in to moderate the use of Stack Overflow in my classroom, but sign out of the main site to avoid distractions there.

So here are my questions:

1. Can I sign out of my main account and sign in **only** to my institutional account?
2. Can I disassociate my institutional account from my main account -- essentially undoing the "I already have a stack exchange account" check-box that I checked when I signed up for my institutional account about a month ago?
3. Is it possible to delete my new institutional account without also deleting my main Stack Overflow account?  This would be a potential path to answer question #2.

From some basic reading, I can see that disassociation of accounts is **generally** not possible, but the typical solution, leaving the MSOE team from my SO account, is not trivial.

Answer (score 4):

This is ... complicated. From a high level, Teams accounts are not wholly separate accounts from Stack Overflow accounts (although the data is logically separated). When you join a Team, we simply attach Team credentials to your Stack Overflow account. If you delete your Stack Overflow account, you would also lose access to any Teams you are a member of.

Going through your questions:

1. No. You cannot be signed out of Stack Overflow and remain signed into your Team.
2. Yes, you can dissociate a Team account from your SO accounts by going to your profile, then "Edit profile and settings" -> "My team". You will, however, lose access to the Team.
3. No. Teams accounts cannot be deleted, only deactivated or anonymized via a GDPR request. See #2 for removing a Team from your SO account.

The only workaround is to create a second Stack Overflow account specifically for Teams use. You can then dissociated the Team from your personal account and then send an e-mail to teams-support at stackoverflow dot com. We can work with you to attach the old Teams account to a different SO account.

You will need to be conscious of switching accounts when accessing your Team. Depending on how the Teams permissions are set, users have a tendency to forget to switch SO accounts and then wind up with multiple accounts on the same Team.

Comment: The response is appreciated. The lack of real solutions, not so much. Hopefully this will be solved at some point. Having my personal and corporate identities linked is not desirable. Even if not a direct inconvenience right now (for me), this kind of thing can easily have  unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Conversely,  is it possible to merge SO accounts and a Teams account in the future?

Comment: For anyone starting to follow these instructions from this page, remember that you need to go to your `stackoverflow.com` profile, not start here with your `meta.stackoverflow.com` profile.

Comment: These instructions are now obsolete. In particular, you should NOT disassociate your SO account from the MS Teams account.  See [my new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420508/1048186)

Answer (score 3):

**I have successfully disassociated this account from my institutional SO Teams account.**  I'm very happy with the result.  It's not hard to log out and log in between the two accounts or to open the second account through a second browser identity.

And after the transition to the new domain, https://stackoverflowteams.com, the situation is even better! I can now be logged into both accounts at the same time, or only one of them, with perfect flexibility.

Since this meta question seems to be wildly popular (at least for one of mine), let me write a bit about my experience, which while successful, took a while.

**Key things to know up front:**

- **You will need help from another admin on your institution's SO Team**, even if you are yourself an admin on that team. You CANNOT be the sole admin on your team when following these instructions. You will need the help of another admin to make this work. I tried to minimize the amount of support needed by this other admin, and I'm hoping this guide will help.
- You will need to create a second SO account to be associated with your institution's SO Team

To Stack Overflow (the company's) credit, this is a process that they don't do very often and so it doesn't make sense to automate it on the back end.  The support staff were very friendly and reasonably responsive throughout the whole process. Much of the delay was on my end.

### These instructions are for those who are NOT an admin on their team's site and don't want to be.

1. For anyone starting to follow these instructions from this page, remember that you need to go to your stackoverflow.com profile, not start here with your meta.stackoverflow.com profile.
2. I suggest writing to your institutional Teams admin:

   > Hello <fellow admin at my institution>,
   >
   > Can you please send this email to Stack Overflow technical support <teams-support@stackoverflow.com> to authorize switching which of my Stack Overflow accounts is affiliated with <My Institution>?
   >
   > > Hello SO Teams Support,
   > >
   > > As admin for <My Institution>, I would like you to change the SO account associated with <Your Name Here>'s SO Teams Account.
   > >
   > > Can you please move me@my_instition.edu and the associated account to second_email@gmail.com?
   > >
   > > Following Josiah Yoder's answer (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/TBA/TBA), <Your Name Here> has NOT disassociated my Stack Overflow MSOE Teams account from my main SO account. But I have
   > > created a new account to which to transfer my account.
   > >
   > > His/her main SO account is
   > > https://stackoverflow.com/users/nnnn/my-name,
   > >
   > > His/her new SO account is:
   > > https://stackoverflow.com/users/nnnnnn/me-at-my-institution
   > >
   > > His/her main SO email is first_email@gmail.com
   > > His/her new SO email is second_email@gmail.com
   > > His/her MSOE Teams email is me@my_institution.edu
   > >
   > > Can you please move me@my_institution.edu and the <My Institution> Teams account to second_email@gmail.com?
   > >
   > > Thank you,
   > > Your Friendly Admin's name here.
   > > SO Admin for <My Institution>
   > > Thank you,
   > > Your Name Here
3. Once you are notified that this was successful, confirm that logging out of SO and into the new account is affiliated with my institutional email (and the institutional SO Team)

### These instructions are for those who desire to be an admin on the site.

1. For anyone starting to follow these instructions from this page, remember that you need to go to your stackoverflow.com profile, not start here with your meta.stackoverflow.com profile.
2. If you are not already an admin, I suggest writing to your institutional Teams admin:

   > Can you make me a Teams admin for <my institution's> Stack Overflow Teams? (This is different from Microsoft Teams.)
   >
   > Here are the instructions:
   > https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000190444-grant-or-revoke-admin-rights
   >
   > It looks like under Settings (on the left) -> Manage Users, you should see a list of users, and then have three dots that leads to an option “Make Admin”
   >
   > Thank you!
   > Your Name Here
3. Once you are an admin, I suggest sending this email to mailto:teams-support@stackoverflow.com

   > Hello,
   >
   > Can you please move me@my_instition.edu and the associated account to second_email@gmail.com
   >
   > Following Josiah Yoder's answer (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/TBA/TBA) I have NOT disassociated my Stack Overflow MSOE Teams account from my main SO account. But I have
   > created a new account to which to transfer my account.
   >
   > My main SO account is
   > https://stackoverflow.com/users/nnnn/my-name
   >
   > My new SO account is:
   > https://stackoverflow.com/users/nnnnnn/me-at-my-institution
   >
   > My main SO email is first_email@gmail.com
   > My new SO email is second_email@gmail.com
   > My MSOE Teams email is me@my_institution.edu
   >
   > Can you please move me@my_institution.edu and the <My Institution> Teams account to second_email@gmail.com?
   >
   > Thank you,
   > Your Name Here
4. Confirm that logging out of SO and into the new account is affiliated with my institutional email (and the institutional SO Team)
5. Ask the other admin at my institution to make me an admin again.

   > Could you make me an admin on Stack Overflow msoe teams one more time?
   >
   > I changed which email address I was using for my MSOE stack overflow, and in the process, I lost my admin status.